# Calling Django Function from JS Ajax not working

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I am trying to call a python function that calculates and converts some number input from a user form.

I have an onclick button event to call the following JS function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"/calc_ha_range/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'ra_deg' : ra_deg, 'dec_deg': dec_deg, 'glon_deg': glon_deg, 'glat_deg': glat_deg},
    success: function(data) {

        jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

        ha_start.setAttribute('min', jsonData.min);
        ha_start.setAttribute('max', jsonData.max);
        
        ha_end.setAttribute('min', jsonData.min);
        ha_end.setAttribute('max', jsonData.max); // data.min = minimum val for HA range
    }
})
```

I then have a django url mapping in the form of

```
    import home.views, sensitivity_radec_astro.views,sensitivity_radec_astro_show.views, sensitivity_map.views, sensitivity_map_show.views, sensitivity_radec_vs_freq.views, sensitivity_radec_vs_freq_show.views, sensitivity_radec_vs_lst.views, sensitivity_radec_vs_lst_show.views, sensitivity_vs_freq.views, sensitivity_vs_freq_show.views, sensitivity_vs_lst.views, sensitivity_vs_lst_show.views, utils.sensitivity_db

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home.views.load),
    path('sensitivity_radec_astro/', sensitivity_radec_astro.views.load),
    path('sensitivity_radec_astro_show/', sensitivity_radec_astro_show.views.sensitivity_radec_astro_show), 
    path('sensitivity_map/', sensitivity_map.views.load),
    path('sensitivity_map_show/', sensitivity_map_show.views.sensitivity_map_show),
    path('sensitivity_radec_vs_freq/', sensitivity_radec_vs_freq.views.load),
    path('sensitivity_radec_vs_freq_show/', sensitivity_radec_vs_freq_show.views.sensitivity_radec_vs_freq_show),
    path('sensitivity_radec_vs_lst/', sensitivity_radec_vs_lst.views.load),
    path('sensitivity_radec_vs_lst_show/', sensitivity_radec_vs_lst_show.views.sensitivity_radec_vs_lst_show),
    path('sensitivity_vs_freq/', sensitivity_vs_freq.views.load),
    path('sensitivity_vs_freq_show/', sensitivity_vs_freq_show.views.sensitivity_vs_freq_show),
    path('sensitivity_vs_lst/', sensitivity_vs_lst.views.load),
    path('sensitivity_vs_lst_show/', sensitivity_vs_lst_show.views.sensitivity_vs_lst_show),
    path('calc_ha_range/', utils.sensitivity_db.calc_hour_angle_range)

]
```

which refers to the following python function

```
def calc_hour_angle_range( request ):

   geo_lat = EarthLocation.from_geodetic(lon="XXXX",lat="XXXX",height=XXXX).lat.value

   if request.method == "POST":

      ra_deg, dec_deg, glon_deg, glat_deg = request.POST["ra_deg"], request.POST["dec_deg"], request.POST["glon_deg"], request.POST["glat_deg"]

      tan_geo_lat = math.tan( geo_lat*(math.pi/180.00) )
      tan_dec     = math.tan( dec_deg*(math.pi/180.00) )
      cos_ha = -tan_dec * tan_geo_lat
      
      ha_rad = math.acos( cos_ha )
      ha_deg = ha_rad*(180.00/math.pi)
      ha_h   = ha_deg/15.00
      
  

      output = {'min': -math.fabs(ha_h), 'max': +math.fabs(ha_h)}
```

My issue is when the ajax call takes place in the onClick function I get an error in the console saying 404: mysite.com/calc_ha_range/ not found

I have taken over this project from another amateur developer so my understanding of ajax and django is quite fragmented

Comment: Share your full urls.py

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby edited original post to show full file. All other url mappings work fine